# Suggestion code is not working using flutter sdk in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio

After dot does not suggest libraries like- Colors.white, Icons.add, MainAxisAlignment.center

[image]

I'm Trying :

1. Flutter Clean
2. Flutter Pub get
3. Invalidate caches/Restart
4. Flutter Upgrade
5. Flutter SDK folder delete and again download
6. Android Studio re-install

But not fixed!

Please suggest how to fix it.

Comment: Do you have the Flutter plugin installed in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you installed the flutter plugin for Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, I have installed it.